# Creating Polar Area Chart using Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, charts, html5-canvas

I am trying to create Polar Area Chart using canvas here :

http://jsfiddle.net/wm7pwL2w/2/

**Code:**

```
var myColor = ["#ff0", "#00f", "#002", "#003", "#004"];
var myData = [10, 30, 20, 60, 40];
var myRadius = [120, 80, 40, 70, 40];

function getTotal() {
    var myTotal = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < myData.length; j++) {
        myTotal += (typeof myData[j] == 'number') ? myData[j] : 0;
    }
    return myTotal;
}

function plotData() {
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var lastend = 0;
    var myTotal = getTotal();

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(200, 150);
        ctx.arc(200, 150, myRadius[i], lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (myData[i] / myTotal)), false);
        console.log(myRadius[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(200, 150);
        ctx.fill();
        lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (myData[i] / myTotal);
    }
}

plotData();
```

**Update:**
To clear things out this is what I want to implement :

<[image: http://s15.postimg.org/fnyjfnffv/Coxcomb_chart.jpg]>

This style with this :

[image]

(This is a simple pie chart)
I am not able to implement the second part(exploding the slices) with my current implementation.

Comment: what is this 'second part' you're not able to implement ? The distance between the pie and the center of the circle ?

Comment: yes that distance which will be equal between all slices and also writing text into it.

Comment: So that could be something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/wm7pwL2w/4/

Comment: yeah this is very similar to what I am looking for but the distance should be uniform between all slices.

Comment: hi, var myDistance = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]; setting this I should be getting uniform distance right ? But its not happening. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/wm7pwL2w/5/ Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would use an object model as well as keeping a parent-child relationship between the chart and the slices. This way I can work with just the chart model having it render all the children, and I could expand the slice object to do more powerful stuff. I did not support text in this example but this should be easy to add from here.

Ok, first lets built a parent object - the chart itself:

```
function Chart(x, y) {        
  this.x = x;       // expose these values so we can alter them from outside
  this.y = y;       // as well as within the prototypes (see below)
  this.total = 0;
  this.slices = [];
}
```

Its pretty basic and it does not yet contain all the functionality we need. We could build the function directly into this object but in case we use several instances of the Chart object it would be smarter to share that memory-space between each instance, so we're gonna use the prototype model instead.

Lets first make a function to add a `Slice` object:

```
Chart.prototype.addSlice = function(data, radius, color, offset) {

  var slice = new Slice(data, radius, color, offset);

  this.slices.push(slice);  // add slice to internal array
  this.total += data;       // update total value

  return this;              // just to make call chain-able
};
```

Here we see it creates a `Slice` object (see below), then adds it to the slice array, updates the total sum and returns itself so we can chain it.

The `Slice` object (child) is fairly simple here, but by keeping it as an object rather than a literal object or an array we can expand it later with powerful functionality if we want with little to no modification of parent (you could have parent call a render vector on each slice itself to render itself instead of doing it in parent). Besides from that, objects compile well within modern browsers:

```
function Slice(data, radius, color, offset) {
  this.data = data;           // self-expl.
  this.radius = radius
  this.color = color;  
  this.offset = offset || 0;  // default to 0 if non is given
}
```

That's about it. We support an offset value (from center) which defaults to 0 if not given.

All we need to do now is to have a function that iterates over each slice and render them to canvas at offset, angle, color and so forth.

The magic happens here:

```
Chart.prototype.render = function() {

  var i = 0, s,             // iterator, slice object
      angle, angleHalf,     // angle based on data and total
      currentAngle = 0,     // current angle for render purpose
      pi2 = 2 * Math.PI;    // cache PI*2

  // iterate over each slice in the slice array (see addSlice())
  for(; s = this.slices[i++];) {
      angle = s.data / this.total * pi2; // calc. angle for this slice
      angleHalf = angle * .5;            // calc. half angle for center

      ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);     // move to pivot point
      ctx.rotate(currentAngle);          // rotate to accumulated angle

      // The "explosion" happens here...
      ctx.translate(s.offset * Math.cos(angleHalf),  // translate so slice
                    s.offset * Math.sin(angleHalf)); // explodes using center

      ctx.beginPath();             // draw slice (outer stroke not shown here)
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.arc(0, 0, s.radius, 0, angle);
      ctx.fillStyle = s.color;
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);// reset all transforms
      currentAngle += angle;             // accumulate angle of slice
  }
};
```

That´s it. The order of the transforms is important:

- First translate to center of rotation
- Rotate around that center
- Offset translate based on that rotation + half angle (in this case)

Now we can create the charts and the slices this way:

```
var myChart = new Chart(canvas.width * .5, canvas.height * .5);

// add some slices to the chart
myChart.addSlice(10, 120, '#ff0')
       .addSlice(30,  80, '#00f')
       .addSlice(20,  40, '#002')
       .addSlice(60,  70, '#003')
       .addSlice(40,  40, '#004');
```

For each add the data value is accumulated to a total value. This total value then becomes the value used to find how large the angle should be for each slice:

```
angle = s.data / this.total * pi2; // calc. angle for this slice
```

Here we first get a percentage of total:

```
s.data / this.total
```

this percentage is used of the full circle (2 x PI):

```
pst * (2 * PI);
```

So no matter how many slices we add we will dynamically adjust their angles relative to each other and the total.

Now, simply call:

```
myChart.render();
```

to render it all.

To adjust, and even animate the offsets, we can create utility functions such as in the live code below, or simply set an offset directly for each slice in the array:

```
myChart.slices[sliceIndex].offset = value;
```

Put it in a loop with `requestAnimationFrame` and you can animate it with various offsets and all you need to worry about is 1-dimensional values (anyone care for a sinus wave explosion?).

How you define the parameters and methods for the objects is up to you, but with this you should be able to expand and refine as needed.

Hope this helps!

```js
// Main object (parent of slices)
function Chart(x, y) {
    
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.total = 0;
  
  this.slices = [];
}

// shared function to all chart instances to add a slice to itself
Chart.prototype.addSlice = function(data, radius, color, offset) {
  var slice = new Slice(data, radius, color, offset);
  this.slices.push(slice);
  this.total += data;
  return this;
};

// shared function to all chart instances to render itself
Chart.prototype.render = function() {

  var i = 0, s,
      angle, angleHalf,
      currentAngle = 0,
      pi2 = 2 * Math.PI;

  ctx.lineWidth = 7;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#79f';
  
  for(; s = this.slices[i++];) {
      angle = s.data / this.total * pi2;
      angleHalf = angle * .5;
      
      ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
      ctx.rotate(currentAngle);
      ctx.translate(s.offset * Math.cos(angleHalf), s.offset * Math.sin(angleHalf));
    
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.arc(0, 0, s.radius, 0, angle);
      ctx.fillStyle = s.color;
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, s.radius, 0, angle);
      ctx.stroke();
    
      ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      currentAngle += angle;
  }

  return this;
};

// utility method to add offset to all child-slices.
// offset can be added to each individual slice as well
Chart.prototype.addOffsetToAll = function(offset) {
  for(var i = 0, s; s = this.slices[i++];) s.offset += offset;
  return this;
};

// Child object, slice to be added to parent internally
function Slice(data, radius, color, offset) {
  this.data = data;
  this.radius = radius
  this.color = color;  
  this.offset = offset || 0;
}


// MAIN CODE HERE

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),

    // create a chart instance with center at the center of canvas
    myChart = new Chart(canvas.width * .5, canvas.height * .5),
    offset = 0; // for adjusting offset later

// add some slices to the chart
myChart.addSlice(10, 120, '#ff0')
       .addSlice(30,  80, '#00f')
       .addSlice(20,  40, '#f72')
       .addSlice(60,  70, '#003')
       .addSlice(25,  80, '#555')
       .addSlice(40,  40, '#052');

// render function to clear canvas, update offsets and render again
function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  myChart.addOffsetToAll(offset)
         .render();
}

// initial render
render();

// handle buttons
document.getElementById('oPlus').addEventListener('click', function() {
  offset = 2;
  render();
}, false);

document.getElementById('oMinus').addEventListener('click', function() {
  offset = -2;
  render();
}, false);

// this is how you can adjust each individual slice
document.getElementById('oRnd').addEventListener('click', function() {
  
  for(var i = 0, s; s = myChart.slices[i++];) s.offset = 15 * Math.random();
  offset = 0;
  render();
}, false);
```

```css
#canvas {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=360 height=180></canvas>
<button id="oPlus">Offset+</button>
<button id="oMinus">Offset-</button>
<button id="oRnd">Random</button>
```

Comment: Thinking about it, Slice is perhaps not the best name to could give an object as there is a method called `slice` for arrays - no damage done though, but to avoid confusion you could consider a better name for them in your own code.. (ie. PieSlice or something in that lane)

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to change the values of the Radius 'myRadius', it must be constant (simple math).

```
var myColor = ["#ff0","#00f","#002","#003","#004"];
var myData = [10,30,20,60,40];
var myRadius = 120;//[120,80,40,70,40]; <=====Changed here
function getTotal(){
    var myTotal = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < myData.length; j++) {
        myTotal += (typeof myData[j] == 'number') ? myData[j] : 0;
    }
    return myTotal;
}

function plotData() {
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var lastend = 0;
    var myTotal = getTotal();

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(200,150);
        ctx.arc(200,150,myRadius,lastend,lastend+(Math.PI*2*(myData[i]/myTotal)),false);//<=====And Changed here
        console.log(myRadius[i]);
        ctx.lineTo(200,150);
        ctx.fill();
        lastend += Math.PI*2*(myData[i]/myTotal);
    }
}

plotData();
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/sameersemna/xhpot31v/

Comment: Hi sameer, I have done it on purpose because polar area charts have different radius. What you have shown is simple Pie chart.

Comment: oh OK for that you can use the 'setTransform' function, check out: http://jsfiddle.net/sameersemna/xhpot31v/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wm7pwL2w/8/  This is what I have achieved using GameAlchemist's solution. But its not flexible as per my comment given above on his answer. Can you please explain how your solution will work for dynamic number of slices. What changes need to be done to setTransform ?

Comment: yes i did. But its only transforming single slice. I want to transform all the slices of the pie.

Comment: well yes I just gave you an example