# Rotating charts in Chart JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, rotation

I have a requirement for a chart that looks as such:

[image]

I found Chart JS' [Polar Area Chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#polar-area-chart), but it's not rotated as I needed.

[image]

And since Chart JS doesn't seem to have a rotate property, I tried just rotating the canvas with CSS

```
        #myChart {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-25.2deg);
            transform: rotate(-25.2deg);
        }
```

This gets the desired rotation, but as you can see, the tooltips are also shifted, and any nearby `divs` could be obscured by the rotated canvas:

[image]

Is there some feature/method I'm overlooking to rotate a polar chart without manipulating the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's no way to rotate the chartJS but not rotate the tips** :-\

On the bright side, it's easy enough to code yourself from previous Stackoverflow posts!

A polar chart is a set of concentric wedges as shown in this Stackoverflow post:

[Creating Polar Area Chart using Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210600/creating-polar-area-chart-using-canvas/26371654#26371654)

Tooltips are just text drawn at a specific wedge when the mouse hovers over that wedge. Here's a Stackoverflow post showing how to use `context.isPointInPath` to draw a tooltip if the mouse is hovering inside an irregular path (like your wedges):

[HTML Canvas Hover Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790010/html-canvas-hover-text/30790991#30790991)

Answer (score 0):

Put "rotation:90" or whichever value works the best for you. This option has been added in the last version of ChartJs

Comment: A link to the docs or pull request would be helpful here, or some more information. For example I placed ```rotation: 90``` under the `tooltip` key and nothing happened, so I'm assuming I'm putting the property in the wrong place...